# How do I get file paths of items dropped onto a console application window?

Tags: c#, path, drag-and-drop, console-application

I'd like to be able to let users drag and drop files onto my console app's window so they are not forced to drag'n'drop files onto the app's icon (or link, or even worse write a command line in console). How do I get the list of paths of files I drop onto my app's window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just listen for the keyboard. When dragging a file onto a console window the window gets keyboard events as if the file name was entered directly.

That's how you can drop a file on a `cmd` or PowerShell window and get the full file name as if entered directly and it works the same for your own applications too.

Comment: This is a quick solution, but not very flexible, because you can't tell whether the characters came from drag-and-drop or the keyboard.  So you have to give up the ability to enter things other than filenames on stdin.

Comment: Ok, just dropping a file onto the window makes it look like as if I entered the path to the file manually. But it only works for the one file I dragged, other files are omitted. Is there any way to allow other files paths to make it into my app with a single drag'n'drop of a group of files?

Comment: No, you cant change cmd.exe behavior, as i wrote in my answer. Maybe you should switch to Windows Forms?

Comment: Kamil, what does this have to do with `cmd`?

Answer (score 4):

A console application doesn't own its window, `csrss.exe` does.  As a result, even if you locate the window `HANDLE`, you won't be able to register for drag-and-drop or handle drop messages.  Your console application is therefore limited to the types of messages forwarded by `csrss.exe` through the Console API.  They are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683499.aspx  Drag-and-drop isn't among them, although mouse event inside the console are.

Your best bet is probably to make an application that LOOKS like a console application, but doesn't use a Windows console.  Instead you'd draw text and a cursor on the screen and take keyboard input, creating a command-line interface.

This sort of thing is called a "console emulator", and you can probably find one already built that meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**You cant** because console application has no window. It has standard input, output and error streams.

Window that contain console application is window of CMD application (cmd.exe) and you cant change fundamental behaviors of windows console.

CMD works like terminal (putty, telnet, ssh etc.) - it sends characters from keyboard to application (precisely - it sends characters to "standard input") and displays characters generated by "standard output" of application.

Read a little about standard streams.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

**Behavior of CMD.exe under my Windows 7**

I can pass filename (with full path) from drag/drop. Dropping one "file icon" on cmd window will "type" filename - but there is no CR/LF (line feed) character, so "readline" function will not work.

Dropping multiple file icons will pass only one file.

Sorry, if i made some language mistakes.

Comment: Actually `string path = Console.ReadLine();` works just fine. You just have to press enter after the path appears in the window.

Comment: I dont have to, its your problem :) You may also read characters until you reach .abc where abc is filename extension, to avoid pressing enter after each file dropped.

Comment: It's probably a feature rather than a problem.

Comment: Well, it's really useful when you can check the file path "entered" and pressing enter doesn't take too much time. If there's a list of files to be processed, there is an instruction on how to drag'n'drop them onto application icon, so I'm okay with that.

Comment: I had similar problem (simple mp3 batch encoder using external executable - lame.exe). I also solved it by dropping filelist on app icon, not window. It's ok for me, but not the best for not experienced computer users.