# Is there any way to drag strings onto a console application?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, console

I have a small console program, and I would like it to have behaviour like:

```
*I drag a (URL) string to the console application
*The console application gets the string that was dropped in, and then calls a function with that string.
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to do this. There are no events in the Console class that would allow me to do this, according to MSDN. Can anyone help me?

Note: This is while the application is open.

Comment: does this help? http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/155894-Drag--Drop-with-console-app-C

Comment: @omerschleifer Sorry, I meant while it was open.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How do I get file paths of items dropped onto a console application window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662778/how-do-i-get-file-paths-of-items-dropped-onto-a-console-application-window)

Comment: @AlinaB. It doesn't drop, at all. When I drop it, it doesn't type. (It's a URL string, not a file path)

Comment: It is somewhat inevitable that you encounter the usability limitations of a console mode app sooner or later.  You are definitely pushing those limits when you want to make this work.  There's also the discoverability problem, your user will never figure out that D+D could work unless you tell him.  Creating a GUI app in C# is not that hard, perhaps time to take a look.

Comment: It's just a small app for my convenience, I need to download lots of files so I just copy + paste their addresses in, it'd be even faster if I could just drag them in. Doing a WPF app wouldn't be too much trouble, it's just I was wondering. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Your application doesn't own the window its running in, so that will prevent your program from accepting a dragged URL. Notice how the cursor changes to the verboten sign? The window is checking the data on the dragged object and determining that it can't do anything with them.

Now, you might have some luck by modifying a console emulator such as the open-source [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/), but you would have to be sure that your users are using that same version of the emulator.